# awk: remove duplicate lines with word position exchangable

Tags: awk

**Generally**, my question is using AWK how can I delete duplicated rows within a file, where "duplicate" here include the cases where certain columns are **exchangeable**.

**background** of my question. Originally I have a file like this:

```
10/13-01:55:42.549318  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 10.0.0.3:1045 -> 103.105.0.1:80
10/13-01:55:42.549318  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 103.105.0.1:80 -> 10.0.0.3:1045
10/13-01:56:45.221877  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 10.0.0.3:1049 -> 103.105.0.1:80
10/13-01:56:57.150985  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 10.0.0.3:1051 -> 103.105.0.1:80
10/13-01:56:58.935176  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 10.0.0.3:1051 -> 103.105.0.1:80
10/13-01:57:13.494148  [**] [1:1000003:0] Detect possible CnC comu [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 10.0.0.3:1054 -> 103.105.0.1:80
```

and my goal is to reach the following formated file:

```
10.0.0.3|1045|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1049|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1051|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1054|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
```

**Effort and Progress so far** I used the following (very poorly written) to process it:

```
cat test.log | awk -F" " '{print $6 " " $15 " " $17}' | awk '{t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = $3; $3 = t; print;}' | awk '{gsub(":", "| "); gsub(" ","|"); print}' | awk 'NR%2!=0'
```

then I have a file containing the following sample:

```
10.0.0.3|1045|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1049|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1051|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1051|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
10.0.0.3|1054|103.105.0.1|80|CnC
103.105.0.1|80|10.0.0.3|1045|CnC
```

The first and last lines are considered **duplicated** since they match the following pattern

```
A|a|B|b|M
B|b|A|a|M
```

**Ask for help** I wonder if there is anyway using AWK I can remove such duplicated rows in a relatively large file from the original format without my post-process please? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. Aside from Ed, we are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Comment: veritas, you've tagged your question "awk", but you haven't included any awk code in your question. Please add your work so far.

Comment: Thanks, Graham and ghoti I am not familiar with awk, and I've added some background to my question above.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry I am not familiar with awk. It will be great to process it from scratch, I will spend some more time to learn how to do it instead of asking for help directly :-)

Comment: @EdMorton I really appreciate your help and tried to up-vote your answer instead, though my reputation rank prevented me from doing so. My original post is updated within hours to provide a more detail background on the basis of my question so that it can better help the community, also as per requested by community users. Sincerely, Grail's answer and yours are both *really* helpful for beginners like me and I found others might find Grail's a more direct resolution. Again, thank you very much for your prompt reply and friendly help, as soon as I am able, I'll up-vote your answer. :)

Comment: @EdMorton I just edited the question to help others. Thanks again and receiving your answer within minutes of posting my question was just amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could skip this step altogether and just work on the original data:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ OFS = "|" }

{
    ip1 = $(NF-2)
    ip2 = $NF
}

!(key1[ip1,ip2] + key1[ip2,ip1]){

    split(ip1,combo1,":")
    split(ip2,combo2,":")

    key1[ip1,ip2]++
    key1[ip2,ip1]++

    print combo1[1],combo1[2],combo2[1],combo2[2],$6
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd `key1[ip1,ip2]++` should be `key1[ip2,ip1]++` but in any case idiomatically you should be using: `!seen[ip1>ip2 ? ip1 FS ip2 : ip2 FS ip1]++ { .... }` instead of `!(key1[ip1,ip2] + key1[ip2,ip1]){ ... }` so you don't need 2 array entries for every pair and a separate step to increment them plus everyone knows when they see an array named `seen[]` exactly what it's being used for so that helps clarify the code.